# Show legend using seaborn when hue is not used

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am pretty new to python/pandas and other libraries, here is my code

```
sns.set(style='whitegrid')

plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
sns.barplot(df.genres.value_counts().index, df.genres.value_counts())
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.xlabel('genres')
plt.ylabel('Count', rotation=0)
plt.title('Graph showing the count for each genre in the dataset')
plt.legend();
```

[image: Here is the graph]

I want the color code from the plot to be shown as the legend. How can I do that? Thanks for the help in advance. Any kind of suggestions to make the code more efficient are welcomed

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)